# Jquery Search Filter

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to filter searches. I was trying to get only the 2 columns I want to be filtered using the .filter class. The problem is that the script now requires the text to match in both columns in order for it to filter the results. How do I make it so that it finds results from either column, not both?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $rows = $('#orders tbody .filter');
    $('#filtersearch').keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $rows.closest('tr').show().end().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).closest('tr').hide();
    });
    $('#filtersearch').keyup();
});
```

And the table with the data

```
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="orders">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="6">
            <form name"searchfilter">
            <input type="text" id="filtersearch" name="filtersearch" placeholder="Search by name or phone number" value="<?php echo $search; ?>">
            </form>
            </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="15%">Date</th>
<th width="30%">Name</th>
<th width="30%">Phone</th>
<th width="15%">Location</th>
<th width="10%">Picked Up</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
/* 
        VIEW.PHP
        Displays all data from 'players' table
*/

        // connect to the database
        include('connect-db.php');


        // get results from database
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders") 
                or die(mysql_error());  


        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
     $src = '';
     switch( $row['Location'] ) {
          case '1':
              $src = 'images/rear_icon.png';
              break;
          case '2':
              $src = '2.jpg';
              break;
          default:
              $src = 'default.jpg';

            }      // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="filter">' . $row['Name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="filter">' . $row['Phone'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><img src="'.$src.'"></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="images/icons/checkmark.png"></a></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        } 


?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please post your markup? I have no idea what any of these IDs refer to.

Comment: I overlooked that. Just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace

```
    $rows.closest('tr').show().end().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).closest('tr').hide();
```

with

```
   $rows.closest('tr').hide().each(function(){
       if ($('td', this).filter(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return text.indexOf(val)!=-1; // too much wine to play with ~ things
       }).length>0) $(this).show();
   })
```

A personal remark : naming `$rows` the cells doesn't make the code easier to read and fix.

Comment: I currently have the phone numbers stored in 555-555-5555 format in the database. Since this is searching that column, I'd have to manually enter the "-" for every number I search. Is there any way to get it to ignore the value "-" all together?

Comment: Yes, you can simply remove the "-"  in the function from both the text and the val, just like you fix the spaces with a regex.

Comment: Can I get some help with this please. I tried adding a new regex for both the text and the val for "-" but it's not working at all